# Common Attributes for Button in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, button, attributes

I could see more items in Common Attributes for buttons in Android Studio before, but I can not anymore. I can not see after rippleColor. So I want to named button at text attribute. But I can not see. How can I see more attributes in Common Attributes?

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlXKf.png)

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHfn1.png)